# http2: received GOAWAY [FrameHeader GOAWAY len=8], starting graceful shutdown

Tags: http, go

I built a web app with go net/http package. sometimes server return error “http2: received GOAWAY [FrameHeader GOAWAY len=8], starting graceful shutdown”. how can I fix it?. go version is 1.12.8.

When request the API server returns the error and can not reach the endpoint.

here is my http server codes: [enter link description here](https://play.golang.org/p/t2VWrHFwDrl)

the main problem is some client request causes this issue. I can log only this error.

The client send post request the endpont with json body:

```
POST /api/me/posts HTTP/1.1
```

Host: localhost
token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0aW1lIjoxNTY4OTgyMDc4LCJ1bmlxdWVJZCI6IjZmMDM4YTZiNTRkYzQ5MDhiYThhNjY0OWMzM2ZhM2VkIn0.Vs0Oz8ZuLJIv_KrFww_jolVyIzdTGlFVgVQgG5j1X7E
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 76fc1168-8da1-4477-b32a-c7961515f48e

{
    "description":"Gophers",
    "parent_id":"12aa4332mias1"
}

Comment: What is the question exactly? What are you doing were this response in particular is causing an issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the server code and client request necessary to reproduce the issue.